# Update registration number after insert using trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insertafter

I would like to update a user_registration_number when the admin insert a new user. In this user_number I have to use a specific format. I have to use a created year and after a number start in 5000, every year start in 5000

For example if the admin insert the first user in 2014, the application insert ‘145001’ and the next number is ‘145002’ If the admin insert a user in 2015 it would be ‘155001’. I use the next trigger but it doesn’t work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `registration_number` AFTER INSERT ON `app_user`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE uno VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE dos VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE tres VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE cuatro VARCHAR(100);

    SET uno = (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(YEAR(CURDATE()),3), '5'));

    SET dos = (SELECT  COUNT(id)
                FROM `app_user`
                WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y')=YEAR(CURDATE()));

    SET tres = (SELECT lpad(dos,3,'0'));


    SET @registration_number = (SELECT CONCAT(uno,tres));

END
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does `app_user` table has a column `registration_number`?

Comment: Can you also post result for `desc app_user`?

Comment: Just my two cents, an id / registration number in a database is used to identify a row. Why on earth does it have to be in a specific format? This usually causes more trouble than anything else. And if you already have the information of the year (or whatever) in the table, don't use it twice. If it's a must, create a view.

Comment: This is the description of colum 

`registration_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

I think the same as you fancyPants, but it's a specification that have asked me

Comment: This is my table

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `registration_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` date NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `tel_home` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `tel_mobile` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
)

Comment: Thank you all for the contributions, but finally I decided to do it by code